# slow extraction of json array elements in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a json array and I want to expand each element to a new table. With the new json functions in postgresql 9.3, I expected this to be the best method:

```
create table p as select json_array_elements(json) foo from g
```

To my amazement, a lateral expansion is lot faster:

```
create table p as select json->x foo from g join lateral (select 
generate_series(0,json_array_length(g.json)-1) x ) xxx on true
```

Which is the problem with the first approach?

EDIT: a test case can be built for 20000 rows as

```
create table g as select (select json_agg(random()) json  from 
generate_series(0, (r1*4)::int))  from (select random() r1 from 
generate_series(1,20000)) aux;
```

Over a SSD storage, it takes 3 seconds against 0.2 seconds with lateral. For 40000 rows, the time increases to 12 seconds, while the lateral method just grows near linearly.

Comment: Yup, that's weird. If you can reproduce this over repeated runs, and you have a data set you can share (or can construct one), please post to the pgsql-perform list to mention this.

Comment: @CraigRinger I have added a test case to the question. I will wait some days before going to pgsql-perform, if only to have a more complete case.

Comment: BTW, your lateral query can be simplified to `create table q as select json->x foo from g, generate_series(0,json_array_length(g.json)-1) x;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test case is certainly conclusive, and `perf top -p $the_backend_pid` helps show why:

```
 96.92%  postgres      [.] MemoryContextReset
  0.15%  [kernel]      [k] cpuacct_account_field
  0.09%  [kernel]      [k] update_cfs_rq_blocked_load
  0.09%  postgres      [.] AllocSetAlloc
  0.09%  libc-2.17.so  [.] __memcpy_ssse3_back
  0.07%  postgres      [.] parse_array
  0.07%  [kernel]      [k] trigger_load_balance
  0.07%  [kernel]      [k] rcu_check_callbacks
  0.06%  [kernel]      [k] apic_timer_interrupt
  0.05%  [kernel]      [k] do_timer
  0.05%  [kernel]      [k] update_cfs_shares
  0.05%  libc-2.17.so  [.] malloc
```

It's spending a huge amount of time in MemoryContextReset. Especially given that the profile above was noted down at the 47 billion events (approx) mark.

Backtraces are always like:

```
#0  0x000000000072dd7d in MemoryContextReset (context=0x2a02dc90) at mcxt.c:130
#1  0x000000000072dd90 in MemoryContextResetChildren (context=<optimized out>) at mcxt.c:155
#2  MemoryContextReset (context=0x1651220) at mcxt.c:131
#3  0x00000000005817f9 in ExecScan (node=node@entry=0x164e1a0, accessMtd=accessMtd@entry=0x592040 <SeqNext>, recheckMtd=recheckMtd@entry=0x592030 <SeqRecheck>)
    at execScan.c:155
```

with varying locations within MemoryContextReset, usually at a branch.

Runtime was 836904.371, vs 903.202 for the lateral join at 200k input rows (10x your test).

So I'd say you've certainly found a performance problem that needs attention.

**Update**: [here's a patch](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/52EEF6D8.4080409@2ndquadrant.com) that will apply against git master, or against 9.3. It's pretty easy to grab the source package / srpm and rebuild it if you're using deb/rpm packages of PostgreSQL, no need to switch to unpackaged just to apply a patch.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I was afraid I was going to need to submit a hundred of configuration data files to the list. BTW, no need to wait for me if you want report :-)  I will visit the list anyway to see if someone can find a workaround in the configuration or some quick patch.

Comment: @arivero I'm posting to -hackers with a detailed report now, I'll send you the message-id. If it's quick I might be able to patch it but I'm pretty busy with other work - going to have a quick look once I've finished the report.

Comment: @arivero http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/52EEEC37.9040305@2ndquadrant.com . Will take a look at the source, see if it's an easy fix now.

Comment: @arivero ... and it was. Patch. http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/52EEF6D8.4080409@2ndquadrant.com . If you're running RPM / deb builds, it's not overly hard to rebuild them with a patch applied - no need to switch wholly to unpackaged PostgreSQL.

Comment: @arivero The fix has been committed to master and 9.3, so it'll appear in the next 9.3.x patch release and in 9.4.

Comment: Thanks very much! That should be enough json speed to keep avoiding "document databases" for some time :-D